# Apex 4.2 LDAP authentication - locked out user

Tags: plsql, ldap, oracle-apex

I have successfully implemented the LDAP authentication in APEX 4.2. I am now trying to extend the functionality by using the policy that users are locked after trying to login x times.

This is correctly used in my LDAP server, a user can not login after trying (atm) 3 times. The problem is that APEX displays this as a failed login instead of a message that the user is locked, so the user has no way of knowing why he can't login.
How can this be displayed accordingly?

I am using PL/SQL, for which the package DBMS_LDAP.simple_bind_s doesn't indicate the reason why the login failed. So I checked out the DBMS_LDAP_UTIL package because this gives more return values. Is this the way to go by adding a procedure checking if the user is locked out, or is there another way?

I can't get the DBMS_LDAP_UTIL.authenticate to work though. I copied the existe_user function mentioned here: http://fdegrelle.over-blog.com/article-1311889.html
Running this says my Authentication failed, although I do use the correct user and password.

Any ideas to help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything the password policy extension provides, you have to use the password policy extended operations and controls. In this case you need to use the password policy request control on the bind operation. Then you will get a password policy response control with the response, that will give you the information you need.

Comment: That does look like what I need, but I can't seem to discover how to do this with PL/SQL. Any suggestions in what direction I should look?